# Add file programmatically to IBM Connections Community

Tags: api, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I am trying to upload files programmatically to an IBM Connections Community File library.
I am able to upload to files and then share with the community, but unfortunately is not the desired behavior.

I followed the API documentation (http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+5.0+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Creating_community_files_ic50&content=apicontent)

I am sending a POST to this URL: /files/basic/api/community/{community_uuid}/introspection

I tried using a file Atom Entry document, and Content-Type:application/atom+xml
But it's not working and giving me a 405 with following error:
UnsupportedOperation

-> Request sent

`POST /files/basic/api/community/00f04081-f000-4752-bd88-8b73d281fb19/introspection`
`Content-Type: application/atom+xml`
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`
`<entry
    xmlns:thr='http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0'
    xmlns:opensearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/'
    xmlns:snx='http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn'
    xmlns:td='urn:ibm.com/td'
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
    <td:label>test-restore20</td:label>
    <title type="text">test-restore2</title></entry>`

I tried using the same method than for stand alone file, with a basic header but still giving me a 405 with following error:
UnsupportedOperation

-> Request sent:
`POST /files/basic/api/community/00f04081-f000-4752-bd88-8b73d281fb19/introspection`
`Content-Type: binary/octet-stream`
`X-Update-Nonce:<Nonce>`
Slug:TMap_Next_Book.pdf
`Filename: /Users/Downloads/TMap_Next_Book.pdf`

When I upload to myfile, works fine
-> request sent:

`POST https://greenhouse.lotus.com/files/basic/api/myuserlibrary/feed`
`X-Update-Nonce: <Nonce>`
`Slug: test-restore2`
`Content-Type: application/binary`
`Filename: /Users/Downloads/client-error-log.zip`

I tried the Playground, but not well documented for that part, so so far no success.

Any of you were able to do that, and would be able to share the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include an example of your code - it will make it easier for users here to see what you're trying to do and help track down the issue.

Comment: I am using a basic Http Requester in firefox, trying to validate the POST before even coding. I added details of the POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rightfully this document should be called working with IBM Connections Community Files 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+5.0+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Creating_community_files_ic50&content=apicontent

The introspection endpoint should be called to get the "community collection document feed"

it doesn't look like you have the URL parameter which is required. You should use the URL with a GET /files/basic/api/community/3a246a15-b4d6-44e1-a01d-1c3d89f1f9a4/introspection?communityUuid=3a246a15-b4d6-44e1-a01d-1c3d89f1f9a4

Then you'll look for 
 
Community Collection

Documents Feed




*/*

You'll then POST your file to the href --- https://greenhouse.lotus.com/files/basic/api/collection/e78ba00e-cee6-460f-a9ee-0350bf344e0b/feed

I've asked the team to change the title of the page.

Comment: What to do if I'm getting 400 bad request with this text?

One or more of the following required paramters are missing: itemId.

I visited this URL /files/basic/api/community/589d33bc-c7df-4be2-8acb-a4a6addd367c/introspection to get the Community Collection >  Documents Feed <app:collection href="...">, then I did a MULTIPART POST to that URL, and I gave the X-Update-Nonce with a NONCE